# How to Find a Higher Duplicate ID in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a help with a specific scenario I ran into.

I have a table structure like this.

[image]

In this table(lets call it a user table) ID is the primary key. I want to find the higher value of the ID if the data is duplicated in the username column.

For an example, John is listed 4 times and the highest ID of that data is 10. So i need that in my result.

I can find the duplicate but max id I am having some issue.

Comment: *"but max id I am having some issue"* Have you considered using `MAX`?

Comment: Have you considered `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`.

Comment: Please share your current code and tell us more about what is wrong with it ("I am having some issue")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MAX Function:

Lists both duplicated rows and non duplicated also

```
 Select Max(ID), username from table group by username
```

If u need only duplicated only then

```
 Select Max(ID), username from table group by username
 Having min(ID)<>Max(id)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this will help. I was overcomplicating things